# How can I pass extra parameters to the upload-button component? Vuetify

Tags: file-upload, vuejs2

I'm using the [vuetify-upload-button](https://github.com/doritobandito/vuetify-upload-button) component to be able to upload files. Using the function callback `fileChangedCallback` that only gets the file loaded.
But, I need to have extra parameters to be able to make a logic. Is it possible to pass extra parameters to this function?

This is my code:

```
v-flex.listFilesUpload(v-for="(file, index) in attachments" :key="index")
  p
    span
      | {{ index + 1 }}
  .btns-upload-download
    upload-btn(title="File" :fileChangedCallback="fileChanged" color="default")

import UploadButton from 'vuetify-upload-button'

export default {
  [..]
  methods: {
    fileChanged (file) {
      // Here I need my other variable file because it have the filename.
      if (file) {
        formData.append('filenames[]', file)
      }
    },
    components: {
      'upload-btn': UploadButton
    }
  }
}
```